# How to choose timing of backup for File History?

Tags: windows, windows-backup

I am setting up a backup of my Windows 10 machine using [File History](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2974385/windows/how-to-use-windows-10s-file-history-backup-feature.html). My work policy is that all machines have to be turned off every night, so the backup has to be timed during the working day, and I'd like to set it to lunch. However it seems I can only set the frequency and not the timing. To make sure I get at least 1 backup in each day, I'd have to choose every 6 hours, but I don't want this slowing down my machine (Latitude E5470). So,

1. Is there a way to choose the backup time in File History?
2. Is it likely that backups will affect other memory-intensive applications like Matlab?